# DSP unit usage in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, register-transfer-level

We are using a tool to convert the code into RTL.

Using those VHDL files, we would like to synthesis the code using FPGA.

In the synthesis results, we see the following table:

```
Slice Logic Utilization Used   Available Utilization
Number of DSP48E1s      15     864       1%
```

I would like to search in VHDL files to see which operations use these units.

Is there any way to find them? or any documentation which shows the operations causing DSPs to be used?

Comment: DSP are generally associated with fixed point multiplication

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways that a DSP48 may be used in your VHDL.

1. It may be inferred. This is when the synthesis tool is smart by looking at an operation that you are doing (such as a multiply) and realizing that it would be most efficient to do the multiply with a dedicated resource (DSP48) instead of fabric/logic.
2. It may be instantiated. This means that the primitive was directly called out in your source file. The designer said that I know I want to use this piece of hardware, so I am going to call it out explicitly. This is when you could do a text search for "DSP48" in your VHDL source files.
3. It may be part of a core. If it is part of a core, you may or may not have visibility into that core. For example, how the core is actually implemented may be different than the behavioral model which is used for simulation.

In any case, as recommended by Russell, using Xilinx toolset to determine utilization of primitives in the design hierarchy can be a good first pass to figuring out where the units are coming from. Additionally, you can always open up FPGA Editor, see what the DSP48 units are called and what signals are going to/out of the DSP48 for additional hints on where it is in your design.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to find your Module Level Utilization.  I know that Xilinx ISE supports this.  Under Design Overview there's an option called Module Level Utilization that breaks down every module in your VHDL design and tells you where the Regs, LUTs, BRAMs, and DSPs are used.

If you're unable to find it, look for any large multiplications in your design.  Large multiply/accumulate operations will synthesize into DSP48s.

Comment: On behalf of [Paebbels](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5214707): The generation of the Module Level Utilization (Detailed Report) is not enabled by default. To enable it: MAP Properties => Generate Detailed MAP Report => [x] or add -detail to your command line call.